# changing navigation bar item font size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

How can i only change the size of the navigation bar items on swift? I tried the following:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes =
[ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"CaviarDreams", size: 20)!]
```

but this also changes the font. Is there any function only for the font size?

Comment: Does it have to be done programmatically? You can change the size in Interface Builder.

Comment: Yes programmactically. but also interface builder should work. i looked for it on the interface builder but couldnt find it.

Answer (score 0):

This can obviously be done programmatically, like you have mentioned, but I'm not sure if there's a method to create a UIFont with only a size. You could create one with the system font and only modify the size but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

[There is a `[fontWithSize]` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIFont/fontWithSize:) that you can call on a font that you have already instantiated but I also don't think this is what you want.

You can however change the font size in Interface Builder:

[image]